# When to use Ignite.Net Transactions?

Tags: transactions, ignite, atomic

I am working on Dot Net project and trying to implement Ignite.Net.
Being new to the world of ignite, and after having a read above transactions on ( https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/transactions#atomicity-mode )
 I am a bit confused with ignite transaction atomicity-mode's.

To give you a bit of background, I am working on a project which is being developed on microservice design/architecture, having plans to be hosted using docker containers. So to summarise, I am expecting to have a multiprocess/ multithreaded environment, wherein there can be multiple instances of a microservice and each instance of a microservice will go ahead a create an Ignite Node (Client Mode) and get connected to a cluster of server nodes.

I am dealing with simple curd operations. Each user action resulting in only a single curd operation at a time (Get/Put/Remove/Replace).

So should I go ahead and use transactions (Pessimistic - Repeatable Read) even when I have single operations in each transaction as it locks the respective keys and provides sequential execution and is fully ACID compliant in case of multiple processes,

Or should I just go ahead with the Atomic mode which provides atomicity and consistency but I am not sure about locks and sequential execution in case of multiple processes?

Answer (score 3):

If you need consistency between singular operations like get or put, then [ATOMIC](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/CacheAtomicityMode.html#ATOMIC) cache with [FULL_SYNC](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.html#FULL_SYNC) or [PRIMARY_SYNC](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.html#PRIMARY_SYNC) synchronization mode will be enough. Ignite will guarantee linearizable execution of all operations.

But if you need atomic execution of blocks of code, that may modify multiple entries in cache, or first read some value and then write it back with modified fields, then [TRANSACTIONAL](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/CacheAtomicityMode.html#TRANSACTIONAL) atomicity mode should be used.

Comment: Hi Denis, Thanks for replying! In my case, I have a class with 3 functions for put replace and remove,each just having one operation (simple  PutAsync() , ReplaceAsync() , RemoveAsync() ) But my concern is having multiprocess environment (scaling up multiple instance of same microservice) will atomic mode prevent dirty read in race conditions ..?

Comment: If you get some value in atomic mode, it means, that it was inserted at some point. So, you are protected from dirty reads in this sense.